# Need to use 3rd party router, Static IPs wont transfer

Tags: networking, router, static-ip

I am on a business connection with Spectrum, I have 5 static IPs assigned but they only seem to work when I plug in their own very low end router. The problem is, their router is too low end to handle our traffic level and overheats/crashes constantly, we have tried multiple different replacements (of the same model) and they all did the same. We have a high end Cisco router we would like to use instead, but of course, when we plug it into the modem, we are not assigned our Static IPs.

Is there any way we can recieve them without using their assigned router?

Comment: Did you configure the Cisco router? How did you configure it? If they are static IPs, you'll need the configuration on the router to be correct. 
Work with your account manager to see if they can help you get the config you need on the Cisco. They'll probably not do it for you, but they can give you the info that would be required to configure an IOS device by someone who knows how to do that.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the router configuration.

Comment: This depends entirely on the provider. There are many ways to assign IP addresses on an internet connection. The question cannot be answered without precise information from the provider about the method they use.

Comment: If they're actually static IPs, they're not assigned in any way; your config needs to use them properly.